Evil machine/Alien entity kills man but his consciousness/brain remains alive within it, and he spends eons reading its mind to defeat it and escape
I'm looking to identify this short story. This is all I remember. It was in a science fiction short story anthology I read many years ago. I don't remember any author names or exact details.
Basically, an evil machine or alien entity kills the main character's body and absorbs his consciousness, but he retains his memories while absorbed in the machine without the machine's knowledge. He spends thousands or millions of years studying the enemy from within, reading its thoughts and avoiding detection to try to find a weak spot and eventually escape.
I vaguely remember the entity bragging that it essentially had no weakness, and it reminded me of the Gravemind from Halo.

this reminds briefly of the ending of a scifi movie where the protagonists brain and spine are inserted into a new alien and somehow it has memories of the protagonist and defeats the invasion

@SidharthGhoshal Yes, I believe what you're remembering was the second movie in the series (of two). If you happen to post a separate question about that, I'd be interested. Darned if I can remember much else about it.

This vaguely reminds me of one of the later Polity novels from Neal Asher - an AI goes rogue and consumes the other AIs in its group, and the human captain as well.  The captain lives on within the AI as an aspect that the AI cant quite rid itself of, while the captain gradually learns how to circumvent the AI from within.

@JiminyCricket. perhaps you are thinking of the Skyline film series.

@Moo Could be you're right.

Possibly Asimov's The Last Answer.

An atheist physicist, Murray, dies and reawakens to find that he had been reconstituted as a "nexus" by a creature known as the Voice. Murray is told that he is one of many such nexuses that have been similarly reconstituted to "provide original thought" and satisfy the curiosity of the Voice. The Voice boasts of its unlimited power.
Faced with an eternity trapped in such a form, Murray threatens to seek his own destruction. The Voice tells Murray that even were he able to achieve this, Murray could easily be reconstituted again.
Murray then threatens to withhold any thought. The Voice responds that given eternity, Murray cannot but help eventually thinking.
Finally, Murray vows to seek the Voice's destruction, and thereby ending his own imprisonment.


 Turns out, this is one thing the Voice itself cannot do, and it's the reason for creating these nexuses.


Possibly Larry Niven's short story A Teardrop Falls, set in Fred Saberhagen's Berserker universe - where ancient AI killing machines seek to stamp out organic life where ever they find it. Published in the 1985 anthology Berserker Base and some of Niven's short story collections.
In it, Hilary Gage is a human who, when dying of old age, volunteers to be uploaded to a computer and oversee terraforming a new world. Then a Berserker ship finds him and copies his program into itself before destroying the planet Gage was working on. That ended up being a big mistake...

There was always the chance that Harvest might attract a berserker. I was recorded in tandem with what we called a Remora program. I wasn't sure it would interface with unfamiliar equipment. You solved that one yourself, because you have to interface with thousands of years of changes in berserker design.
I'm glad they gave me conscious control of Remora. Two of your brains are me now, but I've left the third brain intact. You can give me the data I need to run this… heap of junk.


"The three brains consulted, and the weapon swung away."
